# XACML policy at run time

Tags: authorization, runtime, xacml, abac

I am exploring XACML and WSO2 to see if it fits my use cases. One of use case is to dynamically create XACML policies. I want to use role based access control system and my application allows admin users to create roles and assign permissions to these roles. Is there a way for my application to insert a policy/modify policy at run time?

Thanks
Chaitanya

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The Axiomatics API will let you create policies dynamically. Not sure about WSO2

Answer (score 1):

PAP interface via SOAP API:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Entitlement+with+APIs

Java example:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pap/5.X.X/src/main/java/org/xacmlinfo/xacml/pap/is/PolicyAdminClient.java

Python example:
https://github.com/welkson/WSO2-PDP-CacheTest